# Angular2: replace component element entirely

Tags: javascript, angular, components

I was looking around for a while now and cannot seem to find the right answer... this should be something very trivial... and be documented everywhere... just seems cannot find it...

so, I have a very, very easy component/directive called navItem

This is how I call it

```
<ul>
    <nav-item route="/aboutus">About us</nav-item>
    <nav-item route="/contactUs">Contact us</nav-item>
</ul>
```

and this is what is inside it (nav-item.html):

```
<li><a [routerLink]="route"><ng-content></ng-content></a></li>
```

so basically I have just this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'nav-item',
    template: require('./nav-item.html'),
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NavItem {
    @Input() route = '/';


    constructor(){}
}
```

What I get is

```
<ul>
    <nav-item _ngcontent-xng-6="" route="/aboutus" ng-reflect-route="/aboutus"><li><a ng-reflect-router-link="/aboutus" ng-reflect-href="/aboutus" href="/aboutus">About us</a></li></nav-item>
    <nav-item _ngcontent-xng-6="" route="/contactus" ng-reflect-route="/contactus"><li><a ng-reflect-router-link="/aboutus" ng-reflect-href="/contactus" href="/contactus">Contact us</a></li></nav-item>
</ul>
```

Which of course I don't want.

What I want is replacing `<nav-item> </nav-item>` entirely with `<li><a></a></li>`

In AngularJs that was very simple.

Comment: What's in `'./nav-item.html'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported and I'm pretty sure it won't be in the future. `replace: true` was deprecated also in Angular1 since quite some time.

What you can do is using attribute selectors like

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: '[nav-item]',
    template: require('./nav-item.html'),
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NavItem {
    @Input() route = '/';


    constructor(){}
}
```

```
<a [routerLink]="route"><ng-content></ng-content></a>
```

and use it like

```
<ul>
    <li nav-item route="/aboutus">About us</li>
    <li nav-item route="/contactUs">Contact us</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmm, this is not very component friendly... in optic to have comprehensive markup instead of html, non descriptive markup...so <tabset><tab>Tab1</tab><tab>Tab2</tab></tabset> is not possible anymore you would need to do <ul tabset><li tab>Tab1</li><li tab>Tab 2</li></ul> .... Not really clean... Very, very impressed by A2 so far, but this is quite a big let down :'(

Comment: Replacing elements causes just to many issues. I'd rather not use `<ul>` in the first place, then you can have `<nav-item>` children or whatever you want.

Comment: I would, but bootstrap is styling basing (only) on the elements themselves and not classes... afaik (at least when targetting LIs in nav)

Comment: Then the issue is that bootstrap is not flexible enough for Angular2 ;-)

Comment: and in your example I cannot drive classes of the LI from within the component :( unless I attach the logic to the markup...

<li nav-item route="/aboutus" ng-class={{isActive()}}">About us</li>

Comment: You can add `@HostBinding('class.is-active') isActive:boolean = false;` to `NavItem` and when you set `this.isActive = true` the `is-active` class gets added to `<nav-item class="is-active">`

Comment: You can do the same with the `@Component(... , host:{...})` but the decorator binding syntax is preferred according to the style guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is an Attribute-directive not a component as suggested above.

Comment: Can you improve your answer with more information about **why**?